# Inserting Records in Heroku Occurring Out of Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am running into a problem on my production system that I haven't seen on my dev box.

I am inserting a record into a table using active record, getting the result and then inserting several other dependent records that are owned by the original record. These other insertions are performed in their own methods, and the whole thing is wrapped in a transaction.

This works nicely on my development box (Linux running PostgreSQL) but on Heroku it's failing.

After examining the logs, setting logging to :debug and inserting some logging, it appears that the insertions are happening out of order. (In fact the log lines seem to be out of order too.)

This is the code doing the insert

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @transaction = create_sale_transaction(@organisation, params[:sale])
  unless @transaction.nil?
    Rails.logger.info('A')
    create_account_recv_transaction(@organisation, @transaction)
    Rails.logger.info('B')
    create_tax_transaction(@organisation, @transaction)
    Rails.logger.info('C')
    create_retained_earnings_transaction(@organisation, @transaction)
    Rails.logger.info('D')
  end
end
```

Each method being called sets up a new transaction and fills in the data. This is one of the creation methods, they're all functionally similar.

```
def create_account_recv_transaction(organisation, sale)
  Rails.logger.info('create_account_recv_transaction')
  transaction = Transaction.new
  transaction.organisation_id = organisation.id
  transaction.transaction_type = Transaction::JOURNAL
  transaction.transaction_state = 0
  transaction.owner_id = sale.id
  transaction.owner_type = 'Transaction'
  transaction.date = sale.date
  transaction.refnum = sale.refnum
  transaction.description = sale.description
  transaction.amount = sale.amount + sale.tax
  transaction.finacct_id = ar_account
  transaction.save!
end
```

Is this normal behavior for Heroku PostgreSQL databases?

If it is, what is the usual method for working around this?

**Update**
I did wrap the result of the initial save in an if. This didn't make any difference.

Here is one of the log lines.

```
2015-10-19T08:58:17.874036+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "transactions" ("organisation_id", "transaction_type", "transaction_state", "owner_id", "owner_type", "date", "refnum", "description", "amount", "finacct_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["organisation_id", 19], ["transaction_type", 0], ["transaction_state", 0], ["owner_id", 256], ["owner_type", "Transaction"], ["date", "2015-10-19"], ["refnum", "INV12345"], ["description", "A description"], ["amount", "100.0"], ["finacct_id", 14], ["created_at", "2015-10-19 08:58:17.870929"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-19 08:58:17.870929"]]
```

**Update 2**

I found an addon in Heroku called Postgres Studio which lets me look at the production database.

It appears that any other records other than the first are not being inserted in the db.

Comment: I am willing to bet that the normal behavior of PostgreSQL is just fine, and that no work-around is needed. It seems that you have given the rest of us too little to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Looking at the logs, they're showing an insert. But when I check the table using the new tool postgres studio, the records aren't there. I'll update the original question with more data

Comment: Please verify outside of Postgres Studio (it is currently in beta)

Comment: Not sure how since the database isn't generally accessible

Comment: The big question for me is why would the records be saving on my dev box but not on Heroku?

Comment: "It appears that any other records other than the first are not being inserted in the db." -- Why? Are your logger statements not showing up? 

Does this mean that  `create_sale_transaction(@organisation, params[:sale])` is returning nil?

Comment: Do you have model validations which might prevent a record from saving?

Comment: No, the log statements are showing up, and the log lines show the correct inserts (an example is at the end of the question above) I checked the return of create_sale and it returns not nil.

Comment: No validations in the model